# mysql UPDATE statement where pricelist.import_date = ( SELECT max(pricelist.import_date) )

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to complete an update in mysql where it selects only the highest import_date and i cant seem to get it to work. the below statement updates both prices

[image]

```
UPDATE material, pricelist
    SET price = '23'
WHERE material.id = 1936 AND
      material.id = pricelist.material_id AND
      pricelist.import_date = (SELECT max(pricelist.import_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
UPDATE pricelist pl
    SET pl.price = '23'
WHERE pl.material_id = 1936
ORDER BY pl.import_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, in my code i have to update some fields in the material table so i need to keep it in. The above works if i was just to update pricelist

Comment: @JakeStow . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  You should ask *another* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results and explanation.  If you edit this question, you will invalidate this answer, which can attract downvotes.